# wordpress show category and subcategory in menu

Tags: wordpress, menu, header

I am trying to show post category and sub-category in header menu(drop-down menu) but i am  not getting any plugin or widget to show, i tried do some code changes but nothing work. Please give me some suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: I thinks for this need to customized the theme header and write down the custom code for categories and subcategory menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a normal WordPress menu **(wp-admin->Appearance->Menu)** you can **add categories** to the menu.

If the categories aren't shown on the left you need to enable them in the 'screen options' which is located at the right-top on the menu page.

Then you can just add categories as you want to the menu.

Comment: @NiranjanVerma I see you are new to stackoverflow. If you get an answer that fixes your problem you should _accept_ that answer It's the green checkmark left of the answer.

Comment: Thanks Janw... its work, but its a long approach i have 6 categories and in each category approximate 40-45 sub categories. So i want this in a way that for each category it populates sub categories automatically.

Comment: That will be a big dropdown :P But there is no way to do this. Unless you create a lot of custom code yourself.